# Hash Index based Database Engine in mySQL

Tags: mysql, hash, indexing, b-tree-index

MYSQL Server supports different database engine like InnoDB, ISAM, Memory etc.
InnoDB uses BTree while Memory uses Hashing for Indexing Purpose.

My Queries are simple(equality checking) so I don't need a Btree based Indexing so I am using 'Memory' database engine.
But the problem is that 'Memory' Engine data are lost as soon as mySQL server is closed.
With InnoDB, mySQL insert queries becomes slow due to Btree Indexing.

So I need a solution(database engine) which can store Data(and index tables) permanently on disk with Hash based indexing.

Or Is it possible to configure Hash Based Indexing in InnoDB?

I am using XAMPP for development of a framework. I am having large database with 25 no of tables each with 3 columns. Each table can have 10 million rows in it.

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM is persistent storage. It uses B-Trees too, but its insertion speed is 2~10x the one on InnoDB.

Main disadvantages are: no foreign keys and table level lock during insertion processes. (which means you cannot insert and read at the same time, which you can do with InnoDB).

Comment: I need to check foreign key constraint at the time of insertion, So MyISAM is not the solution. 
But I don't need to read the same table during insertion on that table

Comment: Well, I was in a situation like yours once and I ended up trying MariaDB. Maria's XtraDB engine is a drop-in replacement for InnoDB [with 2x performance on inserts](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/01/13/innodb-innodb-plugin-vs-xtradb-on-fast-storage/). However, most providers don't offer MariaDB as a database option.